# Excel 2 Worksheets Events with Different Targets

Tags: excel, vba, events, automation, worksheet

I have an excel worksheet that I want to assign to it more than one Worksheet Event.
To be more specific, I want whenever a cell in column B is changed then one cell to the left (column A) gets the row number.
Also I want whenever a cell in column J is changed then one cell to the right (column K) gets today's date.

It worked for me for both of them individually but I think I may be doing something wrong using them together.

Any help will be much appreciated!

```
Private Sub AG1(ByVal a_Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(a_Target, Me.Range("B2:B3000")) Is Nothing Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Cells(a_Target.Row, a_Target.Column - 1) = a_Target.Row
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If 
End Sub




Private Sub AG2(ByVal b_Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(b_Target, Me.Range("J2:J3000")) Is Nothing Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Cells(b_Target.Row, b_Target.Column + 1) = Date
       Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

**edit - works now (I also added that column can be referred as letter):**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Application.EnableEvents = True

   If Split(Cells(1, Target.Column).Address(True, False), "$")(0) = "B" Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1) = Target.Row
      Application.EnableEvents = True

   ElseIf Split(Cells(1, Target.Column).Address(True, False), "$")(0) = "J" Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = Date
       Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the two code snippets which work independently, and we will help you to put them together.

Comment: just added them! thanks!

Comment: All columns are on the same Worksheet?

Comment: yes, same worksheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the code in the `Worksheet_Change` event and that should fix your issue. This will trigger every time you enter a value for any cell and will only meet the condition if they intersect the range in the if statement.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:B3000")) Is Nothing Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1) = Target.Row
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If

   If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("J2:J3000")) Is Nothing Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = Date
       Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Be sure to add a check for cases where `Target` is not just a single cell.

Comment: i think my code worked but then I changed it. It doesn't work now, can you spot maybe what i did wrong?

Comment: Hi when you say your code are you talking about the original code in your question? Or the provided answer? Also I won't be able to spot what you did wrong without seeing what you changed.

Comment: i'm talking about the exact same one you posted.
maybe we should avoid using Intersect? maybe the use of Application.EnableEvent is wrong?

Comment: When you say it does not work what do you mean? Nothing is happening? You get an error? Or did you got an error when you changed something? If you get an error because you modified more than 1 cell in 1 go then the `application.EnableEvents` is probably still set to `false` Set it back to `True` if that is the case..

Comment: I changed only one cell at a time.
and by saying it doesn't work i mean that nothing is happening

Comment: On the immediate window type `Application.EnableEvents=True` or exit the application and try again. Also you are only entering values in Col B and Col J?

Comment: I wrote Application.EnableEvents=True on the immediate window and restarted excel and it works now. thank you. Immediate window executes what is written there without being related to the macro?

Comment: Happy to help, If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Also yes you can execute code in the immediate window. If you want to read about the difference I suggest have a look at this thread. [Imediate Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350227/how-does-the-vba-immediate-window-differ-from-the-application-runtime)

Comment: one last question, do I have to use xlsm (macro enables) files or can I use xlsx files? (and then use personal macro workbook)

Comment: @Assaf you can get a macro to Run on `.xlsx` files without saving it but when you save it you will need to save it as `.xlsm` so I suggest you use `.xlsm`

Comment: thank you. I really appreciate all your time and help